# cmake. define project languages according to architecture (CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME)

Tags: cmake

My project definition expect different set of languages according to architecture (macOS or Windows).

```
if(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME STREQUAL "Darwin")
    project(myProj CXX OBJC OBJCXX)
elseif(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME STREQUAL "Windows")
    project(myProj)
endif()
```

However, it looks like the CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME is only defined after the project command.
like in this sample code, only the second message will show valid arch.

```
message("CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME: ${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME}")
project(myProj)
message("CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME: ${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME}")
```

Any idea how to fetch the running arch before the project is defined ?

Comment: You could add languages after the `project` call with `enable_language` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is what you intend:

```
project(myProj LANGUAGES NONE)

if(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME STREQUAL "Darwin")
  enable_language(CXX)
  enable_language(OBJC)
  enable_language(OBJCXX)
elseif(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME STREQUAL "Windows")
  enable_language(C)
  enable_language(CXX)
endif()
```

Of course, this leaves no languages configured on other systems, which is probably not what you want...